# Unable to run chromium startup command inside of SH file on Raspberry Pi

Tags: bash, web-applications, raspberry-pi, chromium, startup

I am having an issue when it comes to running Chromium on startup on my Raspberry Pi. I am able to get it to run when I include the command `chromium-browser --start-fullscreen https://www.google.com/` in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` But for my webapp project I want to run chromium after I run an SH file that opens a virtual environment and runs a python code. Issue is when I put the chromium command in my sh file `startup.sh` and run it in `rc.local` using the command `bash /home/pi/MySQLAppTrueTrue/startup.sh`. The chromium browser doesn't launch. Even though all the other commands inside the sh file operate without error. I thought it may be due to the sh file not having excutable permissions so I ran `chmod +x startup.sh` in the rpi terminal. But that did not fix my issue. Do I need to add this permission to `rc.local`? If not, what is the solution to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that at the time `rc.local` is executed there is a DISPLAY

Comment: Doesn't  that mean that ```rc.local``` is being run before ```autostart```. Because autostart works at launching chromium. But my issue is that I get an error in chromium when I try to go to the local address because the webapp hasn't been fully set up. And I want to not have the error at first?

Comment: I mean that `rc.local` is not the good place to launch `chromium`. Even if you could, it would be run by `root`. A web browser with root rights, that's freaking dangerous ;-)

Comment: Does that mean that I should look at getting my sh file to run in startup instead?

Comment: Putting it in the startup scripts of the user would be correct. You may need to add a check for the `DISPLAY` environment variable existence and few more

Comment: Doing this I still had the issue of the error screen coming up, is there a type of wait command that could go into the startup file? Right now I made a .desktop file that is run at startup that then runs my python file.